# Login details not going in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am making a test Web app and I am trying to store my user details in the local storage but Some how, Its not storing in the local Storage which in turn makes my login to fail or there may be any other reason. I am not getting any errors in the console and when I sign up the data is also going into my database.

Code for my Controller:

```
        `(function(){
    angular.module('Test')
    .controller('loginController',["$scope","$state","$http",  function($scope, $state, $http){
        if(localStorage['User-Data']) {
            $scope.loggedIn = true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.loggedIn = false;`}

$scope.logUserIn = function() {
   $http.post('api/users/login', $scope.login).success(function(response){
       localStorage.setItem('User-Data', JSON.stringify(response));
       $scope.loggedIn = true;
   }).error(function(err){
       console.log(err);
   });
};

$scope.logOut = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    $scope.loggedIn = false;
}
}]);
})();
```

and my Html is as follows:

```
<nav class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="loginController">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div ng-show=!loggedIn>
<strong> Email: </strong> <input type="text ng-model="login.email">
<strong> Password: </strong> <input type="password" ng-model="login.password">
<button ng-click="logUserIn()"> Login </button> <a ui-sref="signUp"> Create an Account </a> 
</div>

<div ng-show="loggedIn">
   <a ui-sref="editProfile"> Edit Profile  </a>
  <a ui-sref="logOut()"> Logout </a>
</div>
</div>    
</nav>
<body>
<div ui-view> </div>
</body>
```

The problem is not about any syntax error or missing directory. Please look into this code and help me out.

Comment: `type="text ng-model="login.email">` is that a typo in the original code, or the code you posted here?

Comment: `<nav>` element outside the `<body>` - is that a typo in the original code, or just the code you posted here?

Comment: `The problem is not about any syntax error` - yet there are syntax errors ... if you want help, you need to post the code you want help with, not some random invalid code

Comment: did you try to console response?
and it is not null or undefined?

Comment: also you need to parse the response

Comment: There is no syntax error. I might have missed that while adjusting the code here. So, Please ignore them.

Comment: is your php in json format? if not just parse your response

Comment: I fixed it bro. Thanks anyway. Actually I was trying to parse my object twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User-Data'))
```

Comment: `localStorage['User-Data']` is (almost) the same thing - he doesn't seem to want to read the actual values in this code snippet, just the existence, so, that wont make a difference

Answer (score 0):

change your code from

```
   localStorage.setItem('User-Data', JSON.stringify(response));
```

to

```
   localStorage.setItem('User-Data', JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response)));
```